# JHipster and database connection

Tags: maven, jhipster, liquibase

I'm using JHipster and when I run `sudo mvn liquibase:diff` I get the below error

```
[INFO] Settings
----------------------------
[INFO]     driver: org.postgresql.Driver
[INFO]     url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost/gastos8
[INFO]     username: gastos8
[INFO]     password: *****
[INFO]     use empty password: false
[INFO]     properties file: null
[INFO]     properties file will override? false
[INFO]     prompt on non-local database? true
[INFO]     clear checksums? false
[INFO]     changeLogFile: src/main/resources/config/liquibase/master.xml
[INFO]     context(s): null
[INFO]     label(s): null
[INFO]     referenceDriver: null
[INFO]     referenceUrl: hibernate:spring:com.cboujon.domain?dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL82Dialect
[INFO]     referenceUsername: null
[INFO]     referencePassword: null
[INFO]     referenceDefaultSchema: null
[INFO]     diffChangeLogFile: src/main/resources/config/liquibase/changelog/20150807132702_changelog.xml
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 9.554s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Aug 07 13:27:12 ART 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 18M/179M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:3.3.2:diff (default-cli) on project gastos8: Error setting up or running Liquibase: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "gastos8" -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

I don't know why the `[INFO]     username: gastos8`.

That is my config file:

**application-dev.yml**

```
spring:
    profiles:
        active: dev
    datasource:
        dataSourceClassName: org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource
        url: 
        databaseName: gastos8
        serverName: localhost
        username: postgres
        password:  ---

    jpa:
        database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
        database: POSTGRESQL
        openInView: false
        show_sql: true
        generate-ddl: false
        hibernate:
            ddl-auto: none
            naming-strategy: org.hibernate.cfg.EJB3NamingStrategy
        properties:
            hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache: true
            hibernate.cache.use_query_cache: false
            hibernate.generate_statistics: true
            hibernate.cache.region.factory_class: org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Liquibase maven plugin does not read application.yml to know how to connect to your database, it has its own configuration in your pom.xml. So you have to put it there.

Why are you executing maven with sudo?
Now, you probably have project files owned by root, it's usually a bad idea.

Comment: I found it! But should I have change change manually? What if I need deploy the application to prod? Should I change again the pom.xml? When should I use spring > datasource in application-dev.yml? Sorry I'm newbie with JHipster.

Comment: Jhipster's datasource is like any other java datasource, nothing special, it's used by your application to connect to your database. Using maven liquibase is not required for JHipster development. JHipster requires you to have some basic knowledge about Spring Boot, JPA and AngularJS. As a beginner, I recommend you start by using H2 (database in memory) for dev rather than postgres, it's a simpler setup and you can switch to postgres later when you better understand how JHipster works.

Comment: @GaëlMarziou My liquibase always try to connect to localhost Database even I configured a remote server Hostname in pom, can you shed some light on my issue? Thanks

Comment: Open a new question and give details

Answer (score 2):

As said in the accepted answer, maven doesn't read application.yml.

But if you're uncomfortable with having database configuration in your maven liquibase plugin definition, you can use maven properties and a liquibase configuration file.

1 - In your `liquibase-maven-plugin` configuration, add a `propertyFile` :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
    <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${liquibase.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <propertyFileWillOverride>true</propertyFileWillOverride>
        <propertyFile>src/main/resources/liquibase.properties</propertyFile>
    </configuration>
    (...)
</plugin>
```

2 - Create the liquibase properties files anywhere under src/main/resources. For instance, src/main/resources/config/liquibase :

```
contexts:${liquibase.contexts}
changeLogFile:src/main/resources/config/liquibase/master.xml
driver:${dataSource.project.driverClass}
url:${dataSource.project.jdbcURL}
username:${dataSource.project.user}
password:${dataSource.project.password}
verbose:true
dropFirst:false
```

3 - Tell maven to filter your liquibase properties files to replace values by maven properties. In `<build>`, ask maven to filter your liquibase configuration file :

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources/config/liquibase</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    (...)
</build>
```

4 - Add maven properties for each profile allowed to launch liquibase goals :

```
<profile>
    <id>dev</id>
    (...)
    <properties>
        <liquibase.contexts></liquibase.contexts>
        <dataSource.project.driverClass>org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver</dataSource.project.driverClass>
        <dataSource.project.jdbcURL>jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/yourDatabaseName</dataSource.project.jdbcURL>
        <dataSource.project.user>${datasource.username}</dataSource.project.user>
        <dataSource.project.password>${datasource.password}</dataSource.project.password>
    </properties>
</profile>
```

5 - Launch liquibase goals with maven and set credentials in the command line :

```
mvn resources:resources liquibase:update -Pdev -Ddatasource.username=root -Ddatasource.password=root
```

Source : [Liquibase Maven Documentation](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/maven/)

Comment: this proved to be a big help for me. as I am new to JHipster, Jhipster also has jdbc url and database username and password in application prod and dev.yml files. but you also have to update in pom.xml file under liquibase configurations. otherwise things will not work as expected. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

In file src/main/resources/config/application-dev.yml

```
datasource:
        driver-class-name: com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource
        url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DBNAME?useUnicode=true characterEncoding=utf8
        name: DBNAME
        username: USERNAME 
        password: PWD
```

You have to change:

```
DBNAME
USERNAME 
PWD
```

Don't forget for production to change

```
src/main/resources/config/application-prod
```

and `localhost` in url: jdbc:mysql://`localhost`:3306 to your url

Comment: Your answer can be improved by explaining how and why the above code will solve the OP's problem. Just dumping some code with no explanation is less helpful for increasing understanding of all future readers.

Answer (score 0):

```
datasource:
        driver-class-name: com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource
        url: jdbc:mysql://database hosting address:3306/database Name?useUnicode=true characterEncoding=utf8
        name: database Name
        username: database user name 
        password: and put here database user password
```

Comment: Please consider editing your answer to format code as code (used Ctrl + K or indent the lines 4 spaces) and please consider explaining your answer a little. You answer, as it stands, is very hard to read at the moment. An explanation of why your answer works will help your answer be even more useful, particularly to anyone who is learning.